# Tools to Clean Semi-structured Data Using Java

Tags: java, parsing, csv, data-cleaning

I use Java frequently to clean data files such as the below.
http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/current/uscanpot/uscanpot-02-12-2016.txt

I try to reproduce the data into a CSV file using the principles of tidy data such as:

**"Each variable forms a column."

"Each observation forms a row."

"Each type of observational unit forms a table."**

As an example using the first table of the above file, a record from my CSV file would look like this:

**Crop, variable, Unit, Year, Value**
North American Potatoes, Area Planted, 1000 Acres, 2006, 995.7

What are some of the libraries/tools/knowledge I should learn in order to make cleaning semi-structured/unstructured data easier using Java?